# References: Undefined control sequence

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am using a bibliographystyle file, bibliography file with my `.tex` file and I get the following error but do not understand if I have an issue with the style file or my references file `.bib` or the way I am citing them. I do get the references listed in the pdf without a "comma" between name and year.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\b@armycorps ->\citeauthoryear 
                           {arm}{2012}
```

Here is the code and the relevant files to download [bibstyle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7sokiqwu6pjq7r/named.bst?dl=0) and [bib](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8tx04rcdl0l9jy/ijcai17.bib?dl=0). Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
n the US Army Corps of Engineers National Inventory of Dams  
\cite{armycorps}, over 50 years old expected to rise to 85\% 
\cite{mitdams},

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{ijcai17}
\end{document}
```

Entry for `armycorps`:

```
@misc{armycorps,
  title = "National inventory of dams",
  howpublished = "\url{http://nid.usace.army.mil/cm_apex/f?p=838:4:0::NO}",
  year = "2012", 
  note = "[Online; accessed 15-November-2016]"
}
```

Comment: What is your entry for armycorps in ijcai17.bib?

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for adding it here.

Comment: The code you've posted is not the source of the error. The error is caused by the use of `\citeauthoryear` which is undefined.

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's true, my bad!

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `named` bibliography style, you must also use the `named` package: `\usepackage{named}`. Here the `\citeauthoryear` command is defined. Strangely enough, this is not installed on my TeXlive 2016 system, while the bibliography style **is** installed. This is inconsistent. So either you have to install `named.sty` separately, or use another bibliography style.