# Problem with the new 2017 ACM Master Article Template

Tags: pdftex, acm

I'm writing a paper using the new [2017 ACM Master Article Template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template), and I've experienced the `Undefined control sequence` messages:

1. `\orcid` — this one's not too important, I can just omit my `orcid`
2. `\@currentaffiliation ->\institution`
3. `…->\streetaddress`, `…->\city`, `…->state`, `…->postcode`
4. others that I don't need
5. `<argument> [\protect \citeauthoryear` — ***this one is critical***

Note that I get these warnings when running their *example* `sample-sigconf.tex`.

While the 2nd and 3rd ones are a little annoying, if the control sequences are ignored, it just prints the institution, city, state, etc. which I can live with. ***However, the last one prevents my bibliography from printing correctly***.

I've looked at [this similar sounding question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342292/5646), but that answer did not work for me (unsurprisingly, because I'm not using the `named` bibliography style). I also experimented with [this approach](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5602), which seems to work, but I don't think the bibliography style it provides is ACM compliant.

Has anyone else had success with this template yet? Here is the command I'm using to compile it:

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make sample-sigconf.tex
```

Here is my `pdflatex` version:

```
▶ pdflatex --version                                                                     
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

Comment: Here, with updated TeXLive 2016, I can compile `sample-sigconf.tex`. Try to update your TeXLive distribution.

Comment: Note: I use `Document Class: acmart 2017/03/04 v1.31`!

Comment: @PaulGaborit, thank you! I updated my TeXLive distribution, and the problem was resolved. Make that an answer, and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `acmart`.  I introduced `\orcid` in v1.15, 2016/06/25.

The current version is on CTAN, TeXLive, MikTeX etc.  There is the development version at https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/, but you probably want to stick to the released one.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I was already using version v1.31 (as described in the `README` file). However, asking TeXLive 2016 to update all *did* fix the problem, though it took a while for the update to complete.

Comment: Could you run your document adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and post the log?

Comment: — is that still useful if it's currently working?

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps the problem is me not understanding what it means to "update" `acmart`, and that perhaps by updating TeXLive 2016, I did that inadvertently. Specifically, when I downloaded what I'm calling the `acmart` files (the ones that are v1.31), while it has a acmart.dtx file, there is no .sty or .cls file in it, which seems unusual.

Comment: After you download the package, run `latex` on `acmart.ins`, which produces `acmart.cls`.